# PHP Login using Facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I am having problem connecting php web application using facebook single sign on.

This is my setting

AppDomain : localhost
Site URL: http://localhost/shop/home.php

Error

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

I just followed this tutorial http://www.9lessons.info/2011/02/login-with-facebook-and-twitter.html anybody can guide me?

Comment: There are [official examples](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/tree/master/examples) shipped with official SDK. And it works

Comment: Have you tried it on anything other than localhost?

Comment: Any site can let me try?

Answer (score 0):

Localhost is not a valid domain , 
there are few ways to bypass the error when working locally.

One way is using [hostfile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) .

Comment: I tried change my localhost to localhost.local I got this problem This web page has a redirect loop